# How could I recover my git-daemon repositories

Tags: linux, git, gitorious, git-daemon

I had a Gitorious install that got old and it is clear now that it is not coming back. I want to recover the repos (mainly the wiki repos) from the repository. I do not want to repeat the long and painful process of setting up Gitorious again, just to get some wiki back out of it...in fact I'd like to clean up the old install soon (remove it). Although, when it was running it was awesome!

I still have the database for gitorious, so I know which .git files I want and where to find them.

I was attempting to setup git-daemon (I'm on a Linux (ubuntu) setup), but I am not having much luck. I was hopeful that maybe I could just copy the 'foo.git' file somewhere and clone it.

Currently my .git files are in user git's home folder. No problem moving them though, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I have git daemon running, but it 'hangs up unexpectedly' if I try to connect via 'localhost', all the repos also have my  'export-ok' file in them too. I can connect accross my LAN and clone any other git initialized directory via ssh, could that help me?

Can I just copy the foo.git (more like a f13f9ed412591ce72f7b3cb793605e93ce.git) file to maybe a git initialized repo and work with it there? Is there a git tool that I could use to expand the .git file? <-- I'm sure Git would be the tool right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.git` is a folder and not a file and git repos are lightweight in that it is just files and folders. You can copy your repo to wherever you want.

Since you said `localhost`, if you want you can even clone the repos with `git clone /path/to/repo.git` and work on the cloned repo. You do not need the daemon or anything else to be running.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I was sooo close, yet so far before I even asked :) It worked out fine, thanks so much. I sometimes loose track of how simple (more like intuitive) and flexible Git can be.